# t-sql : Check if given date falls between Dec 15 to Jan 10 discount period every year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

Table has columns DiscountStart and DiscountEnd. Both columns hold Month+'/'+Day values.

```
 Product     DiscountStart     DiscountEnd     Rate
 --------------------------------------------------
 Product1     'Dec/10'          'Jan/05'        10% 
 Product2     'Nov/01           'Dec/31'        12% 
 Product3     'May/01'          'Jun/30'        08% 
 Product4     'Sep/01'          'Sep/15'        05%
```

I need to apply discount rate for a product if the purchase date is between `DiscountStart` and `DiscountEnd` periods of purchase year. Please help.

Comment: What language?   What is your rate vector implementation?   What is the "Table"?   Give us ... something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
-- test tables and test data

declare @t table(Product char(8),  DiscountStart char(6), DiscountEnd char(6), Rate char(3))
insert @t values
('Product1','Dec/10','Jan/05','10%'),
('Product2','Nov/01','Dec/31','12%'),
('Product3','May/01','Jun/30','08%'),
('Product4','Sep/01','Sep/15','05%')

declare @productlist table(selldate datetime, product char(8))
insert @productlist values('20130101', 'Product1')
insert @productlist values('20130501', 'Product2')
insert @productlist values('20151231', 'Product1')


select pl.selldate, pl.product, coalesce(x.rate, '00%') rate from 
@productlist pl
outer apply
(
 select rate, a,b from
 (
  select rate, convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate) as char(4))+'-' + DiscountStart, 106) a,
  case when convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate) as char(4))+'-' + DiscountEnd, 106) < convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate) as char(4))+'-' + DiscountStart, 106)
  then convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate) + 1 as char(4))+'-' + DiscountEnd, 106) else convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate) as char(4))+'-' + DiscountEnd, 106) end b
   from @t
  where pl.Product = Product
  union all
  select rate, convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate)-1 as char(4))+'-' + DiscountStart, 106) a,
  case when convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate)-1 as char(4))+'-' + DiscountEnd, 106) < convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate)-1 as char(4))+'-' + DiscountStart, 106)
  then convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate) + 1-1 as char(4))+'-' + DiscountEnd, 106) else convert(datetime, cast(year(pl.selldate)-1 as char(4))+'-' + DiscountEnd, 106) end b
  from @t
  where pl.Product = Product
 ) x1
 WHERE pl.selldate between x1.a and x1.b
) x
```

Comment: Thank you t-clausen.dk. Very helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're storing your date bounds like this, but I would suggest using 
`WHERE <PurchaseDate> BETWEEN DiscountStart and DiscountEnd` generally. I would parse out the 3 letter code and replace it with a number, then add the year. Like this:

```
SELECT p.Price * DiscTbl.Rate DiscountedRate, *
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        Product, 
        CASE LEFT(DiscountStart, 3) 
          WHEN 'JAN' THEN '01' 
          WHEN 'FEB' THEN '02'
          WHEN 'MAR' THEN '03'
          .
          .
          .
          ELSE NULL END 
          + RIGHT(DiscountStart, 3) + '/'
          + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS StartDate
       , 
       CASE LEFT(DiscountEnd, 3) 
          WHEN 'JAN' THEN '01' 
          WHEN 'FEB' THEN '02'
          WHEN 'MAR' THEN '03'
          .
          .
          .
          ELSE NULL END 
          + RIGHT(DiscountEnd, 3) + '/'
          + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS EndDate,
       Rate
    FROM DiscountTable --Named for the sake of this example
) DiscTbl
join Purchases p --Named for the sake of this example
     on p.Product = DiscTbl.Product 
    and p.PurchaseDate BETWEEN 
                          CASE WHEN DiscTbl.StartDate > DiscTbl.EndDate 
                               THEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DiscTbl.StartDate)
                               ELSE DiscTbl.StartDate 
                          END
                       AND DiscTbl.EndDate
```

Comment: You need to consider the situations that a discount period rolls from one year to the next

Answer (score 0):

To get the applicable discounts for a given date,

```
select
*
from
(
    select 
        product,
        startdate,
        case when (enddate<startdate) then DATEADD(YY,1,enddate)else enddate end enddate,
        rate
    from
        (
            select 
                CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(4),year(getdate()))+'/'+discountstart) as startdate,
                CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(4),year(getdate()))+'/'+discountend) as enddate,
                product, rate from yourtable
            union 
            select 
                CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(4),year(getdate())-1)+'/'+discountstart) as startdate,
                CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(4),year(getdate())-1)+'/'+discountend) as enddate,
                product, rate from yourtable

        ) v
) discounts
where GETDATE() between startdate and enddate
```

From there, you can do a simple `left join` to your purchases to see if any discount is applicable.

Comment: dangerous to use the year from getdate(), imagine the sale is 2 years ago or 2 years from now.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I was using getdate as an example date

Comment: I was refering to the inner getdates. Try using your script for the productlist in my example

Comment: @t-clausen.dk so was i